# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.median1.helper.blog

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create a RecyclerView to read all the text form the Firebase I got this error and make very angry i don't know where is the mistake i did 
i know the error meaning of the error but why it can't convert it.

```
package com.example.median1.helper;

import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class recyclerview extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mbloglist;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recyclerview);
        mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Request");


        mbloglist=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.blog_List);


        mbloglist.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<blog,blogviewholder>firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<blog, blogviewholder>(


                 blog.class,R.layout.blog_row,blogviewholder.class,mDatabase
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(blogviewholder viewHolder, blog model, int position) {
                viewHolder.settitle(model.getPosttitle());
                viewHolder.setemail(model.getPostemail());
                viewHolder.settmain(model.getPostmain());



            }
        };
        mbloglist.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }


    public static class blogviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        View mView;


        public blogviewholder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView=itemView;

        }
        public void setemail(String postemail){
            TextView post_email=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.blogemail);
            post_email.setText(postemail);


        }

        public void settitle(String  posttitle){

            TextView post_title=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.blogtitle);
            post_title.setText(posttitle);
        }

        public void settmain(String  postmain){

            TextView post_main=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.blogmain);
            post_main.setText(postmain);
        }



    }
}
```

and this is blog class which i use it  to receive the data from the database

blog.class

```
package com.example.median1.helper;

/**
 * Created by median1 on 1/10/2018.
 */

public class blog
{
    private String postemail;
    private String postmain;
    private String posttitle;
public blog(){

}

    public blog(String postemail, String postmain, String posttitle) {
        this.postemail = postemail;
        this.postmain = postmain;
        this.posttitle = posttitle;
    }

    public String getPostemail() {
        return postemail;
    }

    public void setPostemail(String postemail) {
        this.postemail = postemail;
    }

    public String getPostmain() {
        return postmain;
    }

    public void setPostmain(String postmain) {
        this.postmain = postmain;
    }

    public String getPosttitle() {
        return posttitle;
    }

    public void setPosttitle(String posttitle) {
        this.posttitle = posttitle;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: i did but i dont thing the problem is with the database structure

Comment: The database structure was needed. I wanted to be sure about my assumption and was right. Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs because of a wrong `DatabaseReference`. I see in your code that `mDatabase` points to `Request` node, which is a String and not an object of `blog` class and that's why you get that error.

In order to solve this, you need to loop through all the childrens of `Request` node. Those childrens are actually objects of `blog` class. To achieve this, you need to add a listener on `mDatabase` reference and use `getChildren()` method on the `DataSnapshot` object in order to get the ojects of `blog` class. Having those objects, you can use the public getters to actually get the values of the fileds and display them in your `RecyclerView`.

If you want to use a model class in the future for your apps, please consider taking a look at [Java Naming conventions](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions).

According to this, the name of your model class would be: `Blog` and the name of a field within the class would be `postEmail`.